# Exception when destroying TReader

Tags: delphi, memory-management, file-io

The following code throws an EZDecompressionError with message 'Invalid ZStream operation' whenever the line

```
Reader.Free
```

is executed. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
Reader := nil;
Decompressor := nil;
InputFile := TFileStream (FileName, fmOpenRead);
try
  Decompressor := TDecompressionStream.Create (InputFile);
  Reader := TReader.Create (Decompressor, 1024);
  SomeString := Reader.ReadString;
finally
  Reader.Free
  Decompressor.Free;
  InputFile.Free;
end;
```

I tested to change the order of the memory freeing commands but that doesn't seem to help. Leaving out the Reader.Free line of course results in a memory leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smasher

TReader does a **FStream.Seek(FBufPos - FBufCount, soCurrent)** in its destructor.

The error get's raised because of a backwards seek. If you call **Reader.FlushBuffer** and **Reader.Position := soFromBeginning** before freeing the reader, does the error disappear?

---

From the comments of TDecompressionstream. *TDecompressionStream is read-only and unidirectional; you can seek forward in the stream, but not backwards.*

Regards,
Lieven

Comment: The error does not disappear unfortunately...this must be a pretty common usage scenario...I'm really confused...thanks for looking into that!

Comment: The error get's raised because the destructor of TReader probably does a backwards search in your stream. Somehow you have to make sure that this is changed into a forward search to circumvent the exception.

Comment: still crashing :( Is TReader not supposed to be used in conjunction with TDecompressionStream?

Comment: How about decompressing to a TMemoryStream and then use that for the TReader?

Comment: @Smasher. I believe Lars' solution would work. Thanks for stepping in Lars. It "is" odd though as it does looks like a common enough scenario.

Comment: Thank you two for your help! It does work when first decompressing into a TMemoryStream. Nice workaround, but if anybody understands why exactly this isn't working as initially expected, feel free to answer.

Comment: The reason's pretty clear, actually: It wants to leave your stream in the same state in which it found it.  It just doesn't quite understand the concept of a unidimensional stream.